# How to set second mail env configurations and make use of it?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I have this env variables:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=accounts@mozcoders.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=accounts@mozcoders.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

INFO_MAIL_MAILER=smtp
INFO_MAIL_HOST=smtp.zoho.com
INFO_MAIL_PORT=587
INFO_MAIL_USERNAME=info@mozcoders.com
INFO_MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
INFO_MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
INFO_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@mozcoders.com
```

And this mail mailers:

```
'smtp' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
],

'info' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('INFO_MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('INFO_MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('INFO_MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('INFO_MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('INFO_MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
],
```

When I send email using the default configurations it works fine, but when I use the custom configurations it returns an error:

```
local.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 Relaying disallowed as default@mail.com
" {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 553): Expected response code 250 but got code \"553\", with message \"553 Relaying disallowed as default@mail.com
\"
```

Here is the code from my Notification file:

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->mailer('info')
    ->subject('Some subject')
    ->markdown('mail.failure', ['data' => $this->failureData]);
```

Comment: Put a real email address on `INFO_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`

Comment: sounds like an issue with the username and from address

Comment: @sta I edited to include the real emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what i wanted by moving this array:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

to desired mailers array:

```
...
'smtp' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
],

'info' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('INFO_MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('INFO_MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('INFO_MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('INFO_MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('INFO_MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
    'from' => [
         'address' => env('INFO_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
         'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
],
```